# Chicago ORD Airport Hotels Shuttle Services and Transportation

Tags: public-transport, transportation, airport-transfer, chicago, ord

I am searching for an hotel in Chicago ORD airport area with a an airport shuttle service and I have the following questions

1. I will be travelling with my family (2 adults and 1 kid) and will have around 5 check-in bags and 4 carry=ons. Is this number feasible to carry on an airport shuttle?
2. Is this shuttle service is free of charge as long as it is specified in the hotel amenities?
3. Is it easy to ride public transportation between Chicago ORD airport hotels and Chicago city center?

Comment: Shuttle charging often (but not always) differs between hotels. Hotel shuttles are used to bags! As for the third, that should probably be a different question

Comment: All of that should easily fit in a shuttle (they are virtually always vans or small buses).

Answer (score 4):

[Google maps returns a bunch of hotels located close to Chicago ORD Airport.](https://www.google.fr/maps/search/chicago+ohare+airport+hotel/@41.978661,-87.8519606,14z) Picking one of them at random yields: [Chicago Marriot](http://www.marriott.com/hotels/maps/travel/chiap-chicago-marriott-ohare/), whose linked website mentions a complimentary shuttle service, as well as [the Cumberland CTA station from which you can take the Blue line into Chicago](http://www.transitchicago.com/blueline/). Sounds perfect for what you are looking for. Regarding luggage, it is safe to assume that they will be used to it and will know how to handle the situation. After all the purpose of these shuttles is to carry people to and from the airport.

Quoting from [the aforementioned Marriot website](http://www.marriott.com/hotels/maps/travel/chiap-chicago-marriott-ohare/):

> #### Chicago O'Hare International Airport - ORD
>
> [...]
>
> - Airport shuttle service, scheduled, complimentary

Comment: I have stayed at the Marriot O'Hare and used the shuttle to get to the airport. It was a roughly 15 seat minibus with lots of space for luggage at the back. There was no charge although some people tipped the driver. It is right next to Cumberland station. The hotels in Rosemont are closer to the airport but if staying there it is best to take the free Rosemont to the Blue line station.